# Posting of link shows correct image not until then when I waited about one hour, why?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, posting

When I create a new HTML page, I have the property tag for "og: image".
After that, I copy the link into Facebook and don't get the correct image.

When I try this some minutes later (about one hour or only 20 minutes), I get the correct image.

It makes no sense for me. Has anyone an advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Open Graph Debugger

(Here is link: [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug))

after you create your post. This should basically force Facebook to process your Open Graph tags. Facebook need some time processing these tags. You can kind of automate it with AJAX to call OG Debugger, but Facebook will not like it I suppose.

Comment: Hi sensor, thank you! I know this debugger. But I don't get this "Facebook need some time processing these tags."? It should process these tags when I enter the link on the profile page, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes I guess it should, but I'm not aware of the internal processing, but I've observed this many times & I found this to be the only  working solution for me. I can only guess that Facebook checks the images in some way or caches them which can cause some delay. I'll be interested too to find out what is happening behind the scenes.